# Duda sobre servlets y jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

La cuestión es la siguiente, tengo un jsp que consiste en un simple formulario para editar los datos de un objeto (clientes), pero para que eso sea posible, primeramente debo de comprobar que el objeto a editar, exista en una base de datos. Hasta ahí todo perfecto, simplemente basta con pasar los datos de un jsp a un servlet, y que me devuela los datos. El problema es que como desde un inicio está el jsp con un get() para extraer los datos que se consiguen posterior a la acción del form, la primera vez que carga, me regresa un null y quisiera que eso no pasara. He intentado de todo y no he podido lograrlo.

Código del JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<%
    String numeroCredencial = (String) request.getAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado");
    String nombre = (String) request.getAttribute("campoNombreEncontrado");
    String direccion = (String) request.getAttribute("campoDireccionEncontrado");
    String telefono = (String) request.getAttribute("campoTelefonoEncontrado");
%>

<body>
    <div>
        <form action = "actualizarcliente" method = "POST">
            Número de credencial<input type = "text" name = "campoCredencial"/>
            <input type = "submit" name = "botonEnviar" value = "Enviar"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type = "text" name = "campoCredencialEncontrado" value = "<%=numeroCredencial%>"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" name = "campoNombreEncontrado" value = "<%=nombre%>"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" name = "campoDireccionEncontrado" value = "<%=direccion%>"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" name = "campoTelefonoEncontrado" value = "<%=telefono%>">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Código del servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
    persistencia.PersistenciaBD nuevaPersistencia = new PersistenciaBD();

    String campoCredencial = request.getParameter("campoCredencial");
    Cliente buscarCliente = new Cliente(campoCredencial);

    if (nuevaPersistencia.obten(buscarCliente) != null) {
        Cliente clienteEncontrado = nuevaPersistencia.obten(buscarCliente);

        request.setAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado", clienteEncontrado.getNumCredencial());
        request.setAttribute("campoNombreEncontrado", clienteEncontrado.getNombre());
        request.setAttribute("campoDireccionEncontrado", clienteEncontrado.getDireccion());
        request.setAttribute("campoTelefonoEncontrado", clienteEncontrado.getTelefono());

        request.getRequestDispatcher("actualizarcliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else {
        request.setAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado", "");
        request.setAttribute("campoNombreEncontrado", "");
        request.setAttribute("campoDireccionEncontrado", "");
        request.setAttribute("campoTelefonoEncontrado", "");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("actualizarcliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es este:

```
<form action = "actualizarcliente" method = "POST">
    Número de credencial<input type = "text" name = "campoCredencial"/>
    <input type = "submit" name = "botonEnviar" value = "Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Tu etiqueta `form` solo engloba al botón, pero para que los datos viajen a otra pagina, cada control html con información significativa (como los inputs, textarea, selects,etc) debe estar dentro de la etiqueta `form`, y si no es así el valor del control no viaja en el submit.

Para corregirlo coloca el resto de tu código dentro de la etiqueta `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el problema puede hacer dos cosas:

**Opción 1**: Inicializar la variables sin valores y luego validar mediante sentencia "**IF**":

```
String numeroCredencial = ";
String nombre = "";
String direccion = "";
String telefono = "";

if(request.getAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado")!=null){
   numeroCredencial  = (String) request.getAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado");
}

if(request.getAttribute("campoNombreEncontrado")!=null){
   nombre = (String) request.getAttribute("campoNombreEncontrado");
}

if(request.getAttribute("campoDireccionEncontrado")!=null){
   direccion = (String) request.getAttribute("campoDireccionEncontrado");
}

if(request.getAttribute("campoTelefonoEncontrado")!=null){
  telefono = (String) request.getAttribute("campoTelefonoEncontrado");
}
```

**Opción 2**: Usar la versión mejorada de "**IF**":

```
String numeroCredencial = (request.getAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado")!=null)? ((String) request.getAttribute("campoCredencialEncontrado")) : "";
```

Esta ultima parece un poco mas compleja pero se puede interpretar así:

```
String variable = (expresión boleana)? "valor si verdadero" : "valor si falso";
```